# DataStax Enterprise: Submitting spark 0.9.1 app to DSE cluster in a right way

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I have a running analytics(Spark Enabled) dse cluster of 8 nodes. Spark Shell is working fine.
Now I would like to build a spark app and deploy it on the cluster using the command "dse spark-class" that I guess is the right tool for the job, according to the dse documentation.

I built the app with sbt assembly and I got the fat jar of my app.
Then after a lot of digging I figured out to export the env var $SPARK_CLIENT_CLASSPATH, because it is referenced by the spark-class command

```
export SPARK_CLIENT_CLASSPATH=<fat jar full path>
```

Now I'm able to invoke:

```
dse spark-class <main Class>
```

The app crashes immediately because of classNotFound exception. It doesn't recognize internal classes of my app.

The only way I have been able to make it work has been to initialize the SparkConf as following:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandrahost")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")            
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
        .setJars(Seq("fat-jar-full-path"))


val sc = new SparkContext("spark://masterurl:7077", "DataGenerator", conf)
```

The method setJars enables to dispatch my jar to the cluster workers.

Is it the only way to accomplish that ? I thinks it's pretty ugly and not portable.

Is it possible to have an external configuration to set master url, cassandra host and app jar path?

I have seen that starting from Spark 1.0 there is the spark-submit command that allows to specify the app-jar externally. Is it possible to update spark to version 1.1 in DSE 4.5.3 ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spark submit with DSE 4.6 which just dropped today (Dec 3rd, 2014) and includes Spark 1.1.

Here are the new features:

LDAP authentication Enhanced audit logging:

```
-Audit logging
-configuration is decoupled from log4j Logging to a Cassandra table
-Configurable consistency levels for table logging Optional
-asynchronous logging for better performance when logging to a table
```

Spark enhancements:

```
-Spark 1.1 integration Spark Java API support
-Spark Python API (PySpark) support Spark SQL support Spark Streaming
-Kerberos support for connecting Spark components to Cassandra DSE
```

Search enhancements:

```
-Simplified, automatic resource generation
-New dsetool commands for creating, reloading, and managing Solr core resources 
-Redesigned implementation of CQL Solr queries for production usage
-Solr performance objects
-Tuning index size and range query speed 
-Restricted query routing for experts 
-Ability to use virtual nodes (vnodes) in Solr nodes. Recommended range: 64 to 256 (overhead increases by approximately 30%)
```

Check out the docs here:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/newFeatures.html

As usual you can download here with your credentials:

http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/opscenter.tar.gz

http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/dse-4.6-bin.tar.gz